# Why do Lego boxes not contain the set numbers in Braille?

Tags: lego-group, set-numbering

Why does Lego not stamp the braille set number on to the boxes of sets?  I know they have made audio/braille versions of instructions, but why are they not making the boxes of sets accessible too?

Comment: This is one of those questions where you'd get more details if asked directly via LEGO Customer Service.